# why can't I write two conditions ? how can I fix this problem?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

```
List<MasterQuestion> questions = _sql.MasterQuestions
    .Include(x => x.MasterQuestionVariants)
    .Where(x => x.MasterQuestionExamId == ed.ExamMasterDetailExamId 
             && x.MasterQuestionSectorId == ed.ExamMasterDetailSectorId 
             && x.MasterQuestionSubjectId == 6 
             && x.MasterQuestionSubjectId == 7)
    .ToList();
```

can I get two or more
equality from same column

Comment: I need two type Subjectid ...

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What are you hoping to see and what are you getting right now? If you can share an example dataset it's going against as well, it could help.

Comment: when I try to get 1 condition its work ( x.MasterQuestionSubjectId==6), but when i try (x.MasterQuestionSubjectId==6 && x.MasterQuestionSubjectId==7) to get two type condition  its not working (my english wery bad sory)

Comment: You should use `or` (||) operator instead of `and` (&&), i.e. `(...(x.MasterQuestionSubjectId==6 || x.MasterQuestionSubjectId==7))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. Either use an `||` operator (i.e. OR instead of AND) for the `MasterQuestionSubjectId` or `Contains`. For example (note the extra brackets):

```
List<MasterQuestion> questions = _sql.MasterQuestions
    .Include(x => x.MasterQuestionVariants)
    .Where(x => x.MasterQuestionExamId == ed.ExamMasterDetailExamId 
             && x.MasterQuestionSectorId == ed.ExamMasterDetailSectorId 
             && (x.MasterQuestionSubjectId == 6 || x.MasterQuestionSubjectId == 7))
    .ToList();
```

Or this which is more readable and extensible since you can add more than one ID to the array and the query doesn't get even worse to read:

```
var ids = new [] { 6, 7 };

List<MasterQuestion> questions = _sql.MasterQuestions
    .Include(x => x.MasterQuestionVariants)
    .Where(x => x.MasterQuestionExamId == ed.ExamMasterDetailExamId 
             && x.MasterQuestionSectorId == ed.ExamMasterDetailSectorId 
             && ids.Contains(x.MasterQuestionSubjectId))
    .ToList();
```